# How to back up an Encrypted Ubuntu Desktop as non-encrypted?

Tags: backup, encryption

If you have full disk encryption on a Ubuntu desktop, and wish to take an image or backup of the installation to put on another computer as unencrypted... What is the best way to do it?

In this case assume it is harder to just reinstall from scratch.

Edit: I am trying to make the restored image unencrypted.. Is this possible?

Comment: The same way you backup or image a non encrypted system.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to backup a system with whole disk-encryption?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/13879/how-to-backup-a-system-with-whole-disk-encryption)